# Set password field in GenericViewSet Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a user in one of my views and store the user password hashed.

```
class DetailedUserViewSet(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetailedUserViewSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = {'message' : 'Invalid data'}
        validated_data = self.request.data
        user = User(username=validated_data['email'], is_active=True, email=validated_data['email'])
        user.set_password = validated_data['password']
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile(mobile=validated_data['mobile'],user=user)
        profile.save()
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        response_data['message'] = 'OK'
        response_data['token'] = token.key
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

user.set_password is usually used within serializers, but in my case I want to also have extra info in my request such as token/message.

This doesn't seem to be doing anything on my password field.
Maybe I have to do it in my serializers? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

`set_password` is method, you can use it this way:

```
user = User(username=validated_data['email'], is_active=True, email=validated_data['email'])
user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
user.save()
```